Create a Search function in Blazor that looks up multiple entries in SQL
Apologies i cant provide the actual code for various reasons.
But i am trying to create a search function for multiple entries in a class
example
I have an Implemented task
public async Task<List<RequestList>> SearchRequestAsync(string searchItem)
{
  return await context.RequestLists.Where(s => s.RequestName.ToString().Contains(searchItem)).ToListAsync();
}

RequestName is one of the values in my Database
This works for that column, but i want to filter by multiple columns.
For context i am very new to this and am building and learning as i go.
In essence i tried to see if i could add the values in the RequestList List to another private List, but couldn't figure out how.

This question is similar to: How to make all fields search in ASP.Net Api. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@Peppermintology Due to my novice knowledge I struggled to grasp how the linked topic fell within my requirements. The answers given here were easier for me to understand and apply.

That’s fair and understandable. The provided solution is simpler, and sometimes simpler is better, but would become unwieldy as the number of fields you re searching on increases. That’s a future you problem though. Go forth and conquer today!

You can compose queries in Linq. I think what you want is something like:
public async Task<List<RequestList>> SearchRequestAsync(string? searchItem1, string? searchItem2 )
{
  var query = context.RequestLists;

  if (searchItem1 is not null)
  {
    query = query.Where(s => s.RequestName.ToString().Contains(searchItem1));
  }

  if (searchItem2 is not null)
  {
    query = query.Where(s =>  /* some other condition */ );
  }

  return await query.ToListAsync();
}

multiple Where() clauses operate in series, so they are AND-ed together.

This works. Thank you. I had to change "is not null" to "!- "" ". As it was not reloading the entries that didn't have a value input for one of my fields.
It'd be great if where() operated as an OR rather then AND. But i can make this work. :)

To handle case-insensitive searches, if your database collation isn't case-insensitive, I suggest creating a lowercase version for each column you want to search. For example, if you have a column named RequestName, create another column like RequestNameLowercase. Do the same for other properties you want to make searchable.
The query would then look like:
public async Task<List<RequestList>> SearchRequestAsync(string searchItem)
{
    var query = context.RequestLists
        .AsNoTracking(); // since you will retrieve results, EF tracking not needed ( this will increase the performance )

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(searchItem))
    {
       var searchItemLowercase = searchItem.ToLowerInvariant();

       // 'Like' function might be heavy but definitely will give more results, but you may use Contains as well. 

       var searchItemLowercasePattern = $"%{searchItemLowercase}%";

       query = query
            .Where(s => EF.Functions.Like(s.RequestNameLowercase, searchItemLowercasePattern))
            .Where(s => EF.Functions.Like(s.MyAnotherFieldLowercase, searchItemLowercasePattern))
            .Where(s => s.MySecondFieldLowercase.Contains(searchItemLowercase));
    }

    return await query.ToListAsync();
}

hope it helps,

Why Like? Bad thing here that you have not escaped search pattern symbols.
